# Изменить порядок масива

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне необходимо изменить порядок элементов в массиве. Например, в массиве есть числа 1 2 3 4 5. Мне надо вывести новый массив, начиная его выводить с указаного индекса, пусть индекс будет 2. Тоисть новый массив должен выглядеть вот так : 3 4 5 1 2.

````
using namespace std;
int main() { 
    int size, i, index;
    cout << "Enter value of elements:";
    cin >> size;
    int* array = new int[size];
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter" << " " << i + 1 << " element:";
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << *(array + i) << "  ";
    }
    delete[] array;

    cout << endl << "Enter index of the first element:";
    cin >> index;
 }```
````

Comment: Ну выводите в два захода: сначала с нужного места до конца, потом с начала до нужного места.

Comment: Перебирайте от 0 до size и для получения исполнимого индекса используйте остаток от деления суммы счетчика с начальным индексом на размер массива.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    cout << array[(i + index) % size] << "  ";
```

Для заполнения нового массива:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    new_array[i] = array[(i + index) % size];
```

Comment: @oleg malanchuk Ну что, получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
for (int i = index; i < size; ++i)
{
    cout << *(array + i) << "  ";
}
for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
{
    cout << *(array + i) << "  ";
}
```

в итоге один массив, просто выводим в нужном порядке

Comment: Только вот мне надо создать новый массив, для работы с ним